# Using datasource connection of weblogic server

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I have wrote Java Client application (bean for Oracle form) to access the data through "jdbcdatasource" created on Weblogic 12c. It works fine when I am running on desktop, but when I am embedding on oracle forms as a bean, it gives following error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource_12210_WLStub

java bean is an executable jar file includes all the dependency jar file, and it is executed independently by double click.

Here is a code:

```
Context ctx = null;
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3:" + url + ":7001");
if(sUser != null && sPwd != null){
ht.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, sUser); 
ht.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, sPwd);
}
ctx = new InitialContext(ht);
System.out.println("!!! WebLogic Server Connection Done!");
javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("myDatasource");
java.sql.Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
System.out.println("!!! DataSource Connection Done!");
```

In the environment of Oracle forms it connect to the weblogic server but could not access the data source by displaying above error.

Any suggestion?

Comment: It would be good if you can share the full stack trace however I think some weblogic dependencies were not included on the client-side.

Comment: I am using maven project that includes all the dependencies, even it work fine by double-click to run it on desktop.

Comment: Here is an error while running on oracle forms to display on java console: preloader: Delivering: ErrorEvent[url=psoft-web-02:9001/forms/java label=java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource_12210_WLStub cause=java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource_12210_WLStub preloader: Enqueue: com.sun.javaws.progress.PreloaderDelegate$4@1b1c3d4 security: Reset deny session certificate store basic:

Answer (score 0):

Just to make things clear to me.

When you say :

"to access the data through "jdbcdatasource" created on Weblogic 12c."

and you code shows:

"javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup("myDatasource");"

The lookup parameter value shouldn't be exactly like "jdbcdatasource" instead of "myDataSource' as you stated before or it was just to explain your situation ?